# How can I make my main code/form to wait for another class' function to finish in C#, without any freezing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, function, class, webbrowser-control

So I have a code that pulls a string/url from SQL, then my code goes like this:

```
WebScrape browser1 = new WebScrape();
browser1.StartBrowser(weblink);
richTextBox1.Text = browser1.wholeText;
```

WebScrape is a class that contains a browser, StartBrowser starts this and navigates it to url/weblink, which then updates the "wholeText" value WHEN Document is completed.

This is StartBrowser:

```
    public void StartBrowser(string address)
    {
        url = address;
        wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += Web_DocumentCompleted;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        Navigate(url);
    }
```

Which goes to my Navigate function to update url

```
    private void Navigate(String address)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return;
        if (address.Equals("about:blank")) return;
        if (!address.StartsWith("http://") && !address.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            address = "http://" + address;
        }
        try
        {
            wb.Navigate(new Uri(address));
        }
        catch (System.UriFormatException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Then my desired variables are assigned when WebDocument is completed as in:

```
    private void Web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        htmlCode = wb.Document;
        wb.Dispose();
        wholeText = getTexts();
        plainText = splitText();
        numberOfWords = plainText.Length;
        webLinks = getLinks();
        imageLinks = getImages();
        imageSizes = getImageSize();
    }
```

Problem here is, after StartBrowser(), it goes directly to richTextBox1.Text and doesn't wait for class itself to finish what it is doing.

How can I make my code wait for my class to be done with Navigate and do this without any freezing of UI/Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight forward way would be providing callback function for your `WebScrape` to call after document parsing is completed:

```
public class WebScrape() {
    // ...
    public Action DocumentCompletedCallback;
}
```

Then you call it when document completed:

```
private void Web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    DocumentCompletedCallback?.Invoke();
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
WebScrape browser1 = new WebScrape();
browser1.DocumentCompletedCallback = () => {
    // may need to return to UI thread here via Invoke
    richTextBox1.Text = browser1.wholeText;
};
browser1.StartBrowser(weblink);
```

You can do similar thing with async\await and Tasks (more "modern" way) if necessary.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much. This was the exact thing I needed, for a function to make a "callback".

Answer (score 2):

> updates the "wholeText" value WHEN Document is completed.

Then why not just put richTextBox1.Text = browser1.wholeText; in your Web_DocumentCompleted method?

```
   private void Web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    htmlCode = wb.Document;
    wb.Dispose();
    wholeText = getTexts();
    plainText = splitText();
    numberOfWords = plainText.Length;
    webLinks = getLinks();
    imageLinks = getImages();
    imageSizes = getImageSize();
    richTextBox1.Text = browser1.wholeText;
}
```

That should solve the first issue, but all of this runs on the main thread.

You could do:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Action(() => browser1.StartBrowser(weblink))));
backgroundThread.Start();
```

Which should move your StartBrowser method to a new thread and in turn your Web_DocumentCompleted event. I'm not 100% on this, so maybe someone could clear this up better than me. Remember to invoke UI elements since you can't access them from another thread.

Comment: WebDocumentCompleted is in WebScrape class, RichTextBox1 is just for texting, instances of WebScrape class will later be used for SQL Queries, that is why I turned into a class to use multiple instances together.

Comment: Ah ok, my apologies. Evk's answer is probably more suitable for you then.

Comment: Yep, it worked perfect and will work exactly with what I was planning to do. Still, thank you too!